# Getting rid of "Cannot resolve file 'client'"-warning in env.d.ts in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, vuejs3

I built a Vue3 template project with Vite and TypeScript and am trying to get rid of all warnings in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 (Ultimate Edition).
This is a warning I'm getting, that I don't know how to get rid off:
[image: Cannot resolve file 'client']

I tried to delete the line, but then the build process fails.

---

Thanks to an answer I found out that the file in question does exist here:
[image: vite/client]
but my IntelliJ seems to be too stupid to understand it, because of the missing `.d.ts`.
When I change it to the full file name, the warning is gone - IntelliJ finds the file:
[image: full_path]
But then the build process fails again, just like if the line were gone.

I tried re-indexing everything, invalidating all caches, I created a completely new project from scratch, but nothing worked - the warning is still appearing.

Answer (score 0):

It's correctly resolved to `node_modules/vite/client.d.ts`:

[image]

Make sure that you didn't exclude `node_modules` folder from indexing

Comment: I didn't exclude it and I can see the client.d.ts file, but it's still not resolving it...so it seems I have another problem :(